# MySQL: Group By Min & Max Value

Tags: mysql

I have below query

> SELECT cped.entity_id, cped.value FROM sales_order so LEFT JOIN
>   sales_order_item soi ON so.entity_id = soi.order_id LEFT JOIN
>   catalog_product_entity_datetime cped ON soi.product_id =
>   cped.entity_id AND cped.attribute_id IN (153,154)

Result:

```
entity_id   value   
2340        2017-03-01 00:00:00
2340        2017-03-16 00:00:00
2312        2017-03-01 00:00:00
2312        2017-03-31 00:00:00
```

Need output:

```
entity_id   value   
2340        2017-03-01 00:00:00 // Start Date
2340        2017-03-16 00:00:00 // End Date
```

So entity_id wise we have to compare min & max value with current date. It both are less than current date then result should display. I tried using having but not working properly.

Comment: Your statements and results do not make sense.  All four dates are before the current date (at least where I am).

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff Updated data

Answer (score 0):

If you want *entities* whose dates are before the current date, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT cped.entity_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cped.value ORDER BY cped_value) as values
FROM sales_order so JOIN
     sales_order_item soi
     ON so.entity_id = soi.order_id JOIN
     catalog_product_entity_datetime cped
     ON soi.product_id = cped.entity_id AND
        cped.attribute_id IN (153,154)
GROUP BY cped.entity_id
HAVING  MAXcped_value) < CURDATE();  -- This condition is sufficient
```

This includes a second column with the values in a list.

If you really want the original rows, then you would put this as a subquery and join back the original values you want.

Comment: This works for me `SELECT cped.entity_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cped.value) as dates FROM sales_order so JOIN sales_order_item soi ON so.entity_id = soi.order_id LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime cped ON soi.product_id = cped.entity_id WHERE cped.attribute_id IN (153,154) GROUP BY cped.entity_id HAVING NOW() NOT BETWEEN MIN(cped.value) AND MAX(cped.value)`